# Is this a bad ide using the MediaScannerConnection.scanFile?

Tags: android, android-mediascanner

I have a `loop` downloading images from the Internet.
I uses the below code to update media content provider with my new image.

Today i tried to download 400 images and the below code run on every image.
So i call this 400 times.
There got to be a better way right?

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(ctx,new String[] { path.toString() },null,new     MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {    

  public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {    
    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");    
    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);   
  }   
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want immediate results then what you are doing seems fine.

If you don't need immediate results then instead when you are done downloading all the files you could trigger a scan yourself of the entire SD card by telling the system that the card was just mounted:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

Comment: I guess the load on the system is less with your answer right?. If one activity uses the SD card, will he be disconnected if i send that broadcast?

Comment: If the user has thousands of files on their sd card, then the media scanner has to re-examine all those files so this might actually result in more load on the system, but most users probably don't have that many files. Sending this broadcast shouldn't negatively affect other applications, but I'm not sure exactly what you are thinking they would be disconnected from.

Comment: Was thinking sendBroadcast would disconnect sd card, but im wrong. Will try both approaches for a while see what happens

Comment: Actually with Android 4.4 you will even get a java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED for trying this. Using MediaScannerConnection.scanFile is the right way to go.